# Adjectival form of the word 'aspect'?

Tags: single-word-requests

What if any is the adjectival form or complement of the word 'aspect'?

I was thinking of using "aspectful" but it seems a bit ugly.

To provde a bit of context, I am working on a framework and trying to name an interface. All of my other names are adjectives and the convention seems reasonable. Forgive me if this is too contrived, but I am looking for a single word and trying to avoid the use of a compound phrase here ("aspect-oriented") if possible.

Comment: +1 for being a good example of a question which is asking for a term to name something in programming, but without being too localized

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, *aspect* has the Latin root *aspectus*, or "to look at". Having searched the OED for an adjective with the same root, there is the word *aspectual* with two meanings:

> 1. Pertaining to aspects. *Obs. rare*
> 2. Grammar. Of or pertaining to an aspect or aspects (see aspect n. 9b).

Note that the first meaning is now obsolete, and the second is only used to describe elements of grammar. So, we need a word which is still in common use. However, if you are using this to name an interface then I believe you can still use *aspectual* on the grounds that it maintains a clear link to *aspect*.

If, however, you are looking for a word which is still in common use, we must look at synonyms rather than true adjective forms. There are several senses of *aspect*, each with [different synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/aspect).

One word which touches on a few common sense--a visible feature, and a part of something--is *facet*. To describe something which *has* aspects or facets, you can say it is ***faceted***:

> *fig*. Having a number of aspects, sides, or qualities; resembling an object which has been cut into facets. Freq. with preceding modifying word. Cf. multifaceted adj. 2.

Comment: +1 and accepted for *aspectual*, thanks so much! The 'faceted' is nice as well

Answer (score -1):

There is many ways to describe one's aspect.

If overall impression of a person is good, [honourable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/honourable) might be the word for you.
If facial expression is the case, [good looking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/good+looking) could be another word(s).
If it is about personailty, [good natured](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/good+natured) might be the word(s).

Comment: The use of aspect to mean *face* is a very specific meaning, and your suggestions are much more specific still; none of them can act generally as an adjectival form of *aspect* at all.